# String Concatenation in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Simple question, but struggling to find an answer.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="key" 
ng-model="main.key" ng-change="updateJson()">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="value" 
ng-model="main.value" >
```

**JS**

```
$scope.updateJson=function(){
  this.jsonObject +=this.key+":"+this.value;
};
```

I have a text field which is bound to UpdateJson, it outputs this as I type in the text boxes.

```
undefinedundefined:undefinedundefined:undefinedundefined:undefined
```

How do I concatenate a String in a way that it recognizes the type correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you outputting, and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: I don't see context or definition for this.jsonObject. Please elaborate what you're seeing on screen. Best is provide a plunkr.

Comment: The value of key would be on $scope.main.key, because of this in the template ng-model="main.key". But basically there are a number of different reasons it could be outputting undefined, but as @Dalorzo said, we don't normally use `this` in angular.

Comment: thanks all, updated to elaboarte I hope.

I read this. should be used with the new controller As moodel

Comment: @Matt Boyle, Provide little more code. So that it can be understood and answered.

Comment: I think you want to do this , please let me kbow if i am not getting you 

$scope.updateJson=function(){
  $scope.jsonObject[$scope.main.key]=$scope.main.value;
};

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$log` is injected in controller, and you use `$scope` as it occurs in your view, try

```
var jsonObject = "...";
$scope.updateJson=function(){
   var keyValue =  $scope.key+":"+$scope.value;
   $log.debug("keyValue is "+keyValue);
   jsonObject += keyValue;
};
```

You should see the key and value entered in your input fields concatenated with a colon in the console.
And the controller variable `jsonObject` should have the key and value appended.

Note: 
If your goal is to serialize some input form fields through json, you should an object, e.g.

```
var theObject = { 
   key: 'some key',
   value: 'some value'
}
```

And serialize it with `JSON.stringify(theObject)`.